# Pinteres save bottom changes sizes between mobile and desktop versions

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

I´m trying to get the Pinterest save buttom running on all the images with this script on [my site](http://laquilla.cl/)

```
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

The thing is that it works on the desktop version and it looks ok, small, well put on the upper left corner on every image when I hover like this: [image: like this]

But on the mobile version the scale of the save icon gets bigger for some reason and it ends up looking like this: [image: like this]

Is there a way to correct this or to disable a js on a mobile device?

By the way i´m currently running BootStrap and a lightbox js on the site too in case there is some known Issues between those and pinterest.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you made provide us with the relevant html and javascript to make it easier for us to understand?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this that's accessible in a browser? Perhaps through https://codepen.io